# iOS: Detect SDKs using IDFA

Tags: ios, swift, adobe, idfa

I was searching for a method that detects if any library is fetching the IDFA before submitting the app to apple store.

I found 2 methods.

Method 1:

```
find . | grep -v .svn | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep advertisingIdentifier
```

Method 2:

```
grep -r advertisingIdentifier .
```

How does these methods differ? As the first one found 1 SDK which is `ACPMobileServices`, while the other found more SDKs. Moreover if one of the methods listed an SDK, does that mean I should let apple know that I'm using IDFA in my app?
Because I'm actually not using it, but `ACPMobileServices` (adobe SDK) might be without me having the ability to control that.